# How can I get objects from property file in another classes?

Tags: java, spring, yaml, javabeans

So, I've Java + Spring class

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.phone")
@Data
public class PhoneProps {
   private List<String> testNumber = new ArrayList<>();

   @Bean
    public void display() {
        System.out.println(testNumber);
    }
}
```

I will use "display" in another class, but when I call it I get an empty array. But Bean method works correctly in this (`PhoneProps`) class.

Example:
When I call in `PhoneProps` class (When works `@Bean`):

```
[998976460010, 998939378668]
```

When I call "display" in another class:

```
[]
```

How can I use objects from `PhoneProps` in another file?
I use YAML file.

Comment: Inject `PhoneProps` in the class that you want `display` to be called from, why are you using `@Bean` on `display` method?

Comment: Moreover you should have `spring.phone.test-number=998976460010,998939378668` property defined in application.properties (or yaml)

Comment: @NisargPatil, I defined such objects in yaml file and injected in the class where I want to call. "@Bean" I use to make sure that it is working properly (to display result)

Answer (score 0):

You have two stages. First stage, load data by create object and second stage, @Bean. If create @Bean, all stages must be in it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yea, you're right. But when I call this Bean method in another class it shows empty array

Comment: Shows empty array, because first start @Bean

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```java
@Service
public class PhoneProps {

   @Value("${spring.phone}")
   private List<String> testNumber = new ArrayList<>();

   public void display() {
      System.out.println(testNumber);
   }
}
```

`@Bean` annotation creates a bean from the returned object of the annotated method, so I guess you don't want that. Additionally, use `@Value` to inject properties.

Now the only thing you need is to inject `PhoneProps` in another Spring-managed Bean and call its `display()` method.

Comment: @UmaralikhonKayumov, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.